# How to select only one Parent and its child checkbox at a time in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4, adobe

I have created nested checkbox in flex.

I want only that one parent checkbox should be selected.
If I select parent checkbox (Cluster1) all child checkboxes of that parent checkbox should be selected, and other parent checkboxes should not be clicked until the current checkbox is unchecked.

[image]

current XML strcture for checkbox tree:

```
public var treeData:XML =   <item name="vCenter Server" type="Server">
                            <item name = "Datacenter" type="Datacenter" checked="false">
                            <item name="Cluster1" type="ClusterComputeResource" id="mycusterOne" checked="false">
                            <item name = "Host 1" type="HostSystem" checked="false"/>
                            <item name = "Host 2" type="HostSystem" checked="false"/></item>
                            <item name="Cluster2" type="ClusterComputeResource" id="mycusterTwo" checked="false">
                            <item name = "Host 1" type="HostSystem" checked="false"/>
                            <item name = "Host 2" type="HostSystem" checked="false"/></item></item>  
                            <item name = "Host 3" type="HostSystem" checked="false"> </item></item>;
```

and Code :

```
protected function chk_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var myListData:TreeListData = TreeListData(this.listData);
            var selectedNode:Object = myListData.item;
            var tree:Tree = Tree(myListData.owner);
            var toggle:Boolean = chk.selected;
            if(this.chk.selected){
                //this.checked = true;
                this.itemXml.@checked = "true";
            }
            else
            {
                //this.checked = false;
                this.itemXml.@checked = "false";
            }
            var toggle:Boolean = chk.selected;

            if (toggle)
            {
                toggleChildren(data, tree, "true");
            }
            else
            {
                toggleChildren(data, tree, "false");
                if( this.itemXml.@type == "HostSystem" ){
                    toggleParents(data, tree, "false");
                }
            }

        }

 private function toggleChildren (item:Object, tree:Tree, checked:String):void
        {
            if (item == null) {
                return;
            } else {
                if(item.@type == 'HostSystem') {
                    item.@checked = checked;
                }
                var treeData:ITreeDataDescriptor = tree.dataDescriptor;
                if (treeData.hasChildren(item)) {
                    var children:ICollectionView = treeData.getChildren (item);
                    var cursor:IViewCursor = children.createCursor();
                    while (!cursor.afterLast) {
                        toggleChildren(cursor.current, tree, checked);
                        cursor.moveNext();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        private function toggleParents (item:Object, tree:Tree, checked:String):void
        {

            if (item == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if(item.@type == 'ClusterComputeResource')
                {
                    item.@checked = checked;
                }
                item.@checked = checked;
                toggleParents(tree.getParentItem(item), tree, checked);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to notify the collection that the data has changed. This will notify the tree to update it's views (sets the data setter in your item renderers).

It is something like:

```
   collection.itemUpdated(node, "@checked");
```

And if you are not using XML list collection you will need to use it.

```
  var collection:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection(xml);
```

Then when you are done making changes you might* need to call:

```
collection.refresh();
```

Everything else you wrote looks fine at first glance.

*On mobile